# Unable to configure services using the extension method in .net

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, extension-methods

I have written a C# wrapper library that targets `.net6,.net7,.net8`. I want to add the DI support so that users can configure it by calling the services extension method `AddMyApp`.

```
namespace Project1
{
    public class FooHttpClientOptions : IBasicAuthHttpClientOptions
    {
        public Uri Url { get; set; }
        public BasicAuthCredential Credentials { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IBasicAuthHttpClientOptions
    {
        Uri Url { get; set; }
        BasicAuthCredential Credentials { get; set; }
    }

    public class BasicAuthCredential
    {
        public const string Scheme = "x-api-key";
        public string ApiKey { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public static class MyAppExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMyApp<THttpClient, THttpClientOptions>(
            this IServiceCollection services,
            Action<THttpClientOptions> configure) where THttpClient : class where THttpClientOptions : class, IBasicAuthHttpClientOptions
        {
            services
                .AddOptions<THttpClientOptions>()
                .Configure(configure)
                .Validate(options => string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Credentials.ApiKey)
                                     || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.Credentials.ApiKey), MyAppExceptionMessages.InvalidApiKeyMessage)
                .ValidateOnStart();

            services.AddTransient<BasicAuthenticationHandler<THttpClientOptions>>();

            services.AddHttpClient<THttpClient>((sp, client) =>
            {
                var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<THttpClientOptions>>().Value;
                client.BaseAddress = options.Url;
            })
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<BasicAuthenticationHandler<THttpClientOptions>>();

            services.AddTransient<ICustomHttpClient, CustomHttpClient>();

            services.AddTransient<ICarsService, CarsService>();

            return services;
        }
    }

    public class BasicAuthenticationHandler<TOptions> : DelegatingHandler
        where TOptions : class, IBasicAuthHttpClientOptions
    {
        private readonly TOptions _options;

        public BasicAuthenticationHandler(IOptions<TOptions> options)
        {
            _options = options.Value;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(BasicAuthCredential.Scheme, _options.Credentials.ApiKey);

            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    public class MyAppExceptionMessages
    {
        public const string InvalidApiKeyMessage = "Your API key is invalid.";
    }
}
```

Here is the `CustomHttpClient` class. I have applied the breakpoint in its constructor but the `httpClient` object does not contain `BaseUrl` and the request headers are empty as well.

```
public class CustomHttpClient : ICustomHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public CustomHttpClient (HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

Here's how I am calling the extension method:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddTransient<IBasicAuthHttpClientOptions, FooHttpClientOptions>();

builder.Services.AddMyApp<CustomHttpClient, FooHttpClientOptions>(option =>
{
    option.Url = new Uri("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    option.Credentials = new BasicAuthCredential
    {
        ApiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();
```

Why aren't the provided `Url` and `ApiKey` values reaching the `httpClient` object inside the `CustomHttpClient`?

Comment: A tip: hover your mouse over `AddHttpClient()` and read what it says.

Comment: @Prolog Didn't understand. There's no compile-time error. As for its docs, it's registering a default `HttpClient` in the factory that can be retrieved by name later. Do I need to retrieve it by name and instantiate the `CustomHttpClient` explicitly? I assume since it's the only `HttpClient` in the services pipeline, it will be accessed using `HttpClient` directly. I am not the most skilled in `HttpClient` stuff, so kindly guide me in a bit of detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close to getting it right, yet two things were holding you back:

#### 1. Registering `HttpClient` for service using implementation type

When this line gets executed:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<THttpClient>()
```

a typed client is registered within the service collection under the name of the provided type.

Additionally, when you hover your mouse over `AddHttpClient()` one of the sentences says:

> (...) `THttpClient` instances constructed with the appropriate `HttpClient` can be retrieved from `IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)` (and related methods) by providing `THttpClient` as the service type.

So, the conclusion we can draw is that your custom `HttpClient` will be bound with the implementation type because that's the type you are passing when calling:

```cs
services.AddMyApp<CustomHttpClient, FooHttpClientOptions>(x => {  });
```

But, your `CustomHttpClient` implements a `ICustomHttpClient` interface and that's the type you are using when resolving it (which I assume). But no `HttpClient` is bound with `ICustomHttpClient`, only with `CustomHttpClient`. You can fix that by adding a third type parameter for the interface and pass it down to `AddHttpClient()` extension method:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddMyApp<TService, THttpClient, THttpClientOptions>(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Action<THttpClientOptions> configure)
        where TService : class
        where THttpClient : class, TService
        where THttpClientOptions : class, IBasicAuthHttpClientOptions
{
    services.AddHttpClient<TService, THttpClient>((sp, client) =>
    {
        var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<THttpClientOptions>>().Value;
        client.BaseAddress = options.Url;
    });

    return services;
}
```

#### 2. Duplicated registration of `CustomHttpClient`

Now, at this point this might work, but it's highly probable you'll fall into a second pitfall. In the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-ihttpclientfactory) about `IHttpClientFactory` there is a registration example:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ICatalogService, CatalogService>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IBasketService, BasketService>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IOrderingService, OrderingService>();
```

with an important note:

> The typed client is registered as transient with DI container. In the preceding code, AddHttpClient() registers CatalogService, BasketService, OrderingService as transient services so they can be injected and consumed directly without any need for additional registrations.

That means that by calling `services.AddHttpClient<TService, THttpClient>()` the extension method already registers `TService` with implementation being `THttpClient` for you. So, if you call your own custom extension method:

```cs
services.AddMyApp<CustomHttpClient, FooHttpClientOptions>(x => { });
```

you'll end up with two registrations for `CustomHttpClient` (or `ICustomHttpClient` if you use the modified version from above). Below is a view of service collection from debugger:

[image]

Registering the same service is allowed, but when resolving a single service, the last registration will be used and the last registration is not bound with `HttpClient`. To fix it, remove this line:

```cs
services.AddTransient<ICustomHttpClient, CustomHttpClient>();
```

I said before this might work, because if you use a different client, it won't happen because the type passed will be different from `CustomHttpClient`, but I suspect that you were testing that extension with `CustomHttpClient` like this:

```cs
services.AddMyApp<CustomHttpClient, FooHttpClientOptions>(x => { });
```

Here's the final code of extension method:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddMyApp<TService, THttpClient, THttpClientOptions>(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Action<THttpClientOptions> configure)
        where TService : class
        where THttpClient : class, TService
        where THttpClientOptions : class, IBasicAuthHttpClientOptions
{
    services
        .AddOptions<THttpClientOptions>()
        .Configure(configure)
        .Validate(options => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Credentials.ApiKey)
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.Credentials.ApiKey), MyAppExceptionMessages.InvalidApiKeyMessage)
        .ValidateOnStart();

    services.AddTransient<BasicAuthenticationHandler<THttpClientOptions>>();
    services.AddHttpClient<TService, THttpClient>((sp, client) =>
    {
        var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<THttpClientOptions>>().Value;
        client.BaseAddress = options.Url;
    })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BasicAuthenticationHandler<THttpClientOptions>>();

    services.AddTransient<ICarsService, CarsService>();

    return services;
}
```

PS I inverted API key validation logic in options, unless you want it to throw an exception when API key is null or empty.

Comment: Great answer. For now, I am not using the interface `IGeminiClient` so I removed it and I am sticking with my existing code. It's working now. One more request. I have a small repo where I plan to use the above code. Kindly let me know if you can spare some time for a code review of it.

Comment: You are always welcome to post any existing and working code for review on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) no matter how large the code examples are. Obviously don't post there whole repository, but a couple of source files from your future library would be a good pick.

Comment: I have posted a question that's linked to this, kindly check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841856/configuration-of-multiple-http-clients-in-di-and-using-with-different-services-i